# Firebase Realtime Database Rules Denied Permission

Tags: c#, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms, firebase-security

I am registering user using Email/Password Sign-In-Method. So after successfully registration and loge in, I can't read and write my data in Firebase Real Time.

I'm new to Firebase so I can't really figure out what the main problem is or which steps I have missed.

This rule is obviously working fine:

```
{
       "rules": {
              ".read": "auth == null",
              ".write": "auth == null"
        }
   }
```

However, this rule is not working, although my user is already registered and has got a UID.

```
{
       "rules": {
              ".read": "auth != null",
              ".write": "auth != null"
        }
   }
```

It always shows the following error:

```
Exception occured while processing the request.
Url: https://App-Name-6ssd2.firebaseio.com/Appointments/-MUAG-CHWBFSv-Vrtsoc/.json?print=silent

Response: {
  "error" : "Permission denied"
}
```

What I currently want is to allow ANY registered user to read/write everybody's information, but it always denied the permission.

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

My implementation for getting Firebase Data.
The error is also pointing to the this method.

```
  public async Task<List<Appointment>> GetUserAppointment(string userId)
        {
            var appointments = (await Firebase.Child("Appointments")
              .OnceAsync<Appointment>()).Where(a => a.Object.UID == userId).Select(item =>
              new Appointment
              {
                  UID = item.Object.UID,
                  AppointmentID = item.Object.AppointmentID,
                  Title = item.Object.Title,
                  Date = item.Object.Date,
                  Time = item.Object.Time,
                  Status = item.Object.Status,
                  ReasonText = item.Object.ReasonText

              }).ToList();
            return appointments;
```

My implementation when a user SinUp for the first time.

```
 public async Task<string> SignUpWithEmailAndPassword(string email, string password)
        {
            try
            {
                var signUpTask = await auth.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password);
                var user = signUpTask.User;
                var token = await auth.CurrentUser.GetIdToken(false).AsAsync<GetTokenResult>();

                await SendEmailVerification();

                return token.Token;
            }
            catch (FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException e)
            {
                e.PrintStackTrace();
                return string.Empty;

            }
            catch (FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException e)
            {
                e.PrintStackTrace();
                return string.Empty;

            }
            catch (FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException existEmail)
            {
                existEmail.PrintStackTrace();
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
```

In order to check whether a user is authenticated/verified or not, i did the debugging and as a result... I can see the same UID in my console as it is in Firebase -> Authentication -> Users.

Here is the screenshot.
[image]

Debugging `GetUserAppointment(string userID)` to check whether the current user is set.
[image]

Comment: Did you forget to include the actual C# code that produces the error?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for the response. I have just added the C# Code. You can go and check it! Thanks

Comment: How do you know that there is a currently signed in user (which is what your rules are checking)?

Comment: Also note that I doubt that `Firebase.Child("Appointments").OnceAsync<Appointment>()).Where(a => a.Object.UID == userId)` executes the condition server-side, so I recommend looking into queries here too: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/retrieve-data#sorting_and_filtering_data

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I can check whether a user is signed in or  not by giving out line following of code: ```FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.Instance;  var userId = auth.Uid; ``` After login successfully I can see the exact same UID in my console as it is in Firebase -> Authentication -> Users.

Comment: That sounds good. Can you update your question to show in the code that you verify that. It sounds like a good assertion to have anyway. It's quite clear from the error that the authenticated user does not make it to the security rules. So either the sign in hasn't happened when this code runs, or it is not being passed to the server for some other reason. Anything you can show to determine which of these two it is, would be mot helpful.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have just update my question. You can check it now...

Comment: Thanks. But that's actually not what I was asking for, sorry for not being clearer. I have no doubt you sign in the user, but it seems like that may happen after the query is started. Instead of showing us code from various places, add a much simpler check to your `GetUserAppointment` method that checks if the current user is set, and then show the updated code (and its output).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen No Problem. I have added another screenshot to my question, in which I debugged the ```GetUserAppointment``` method. I hope, it clears. Not forget to mention, for this step I had to set the "write/read" rules to true. Otherwise, it threw the exception.

Comment: I don't want new code snippets or screenshot, but I want you to make a change in your `GetUserAppointment` method. In there check the value of `auth.CurrentUser` with something like: `if (auth.CurrentUser == null) throw new Exception("No user signed in, so can't load appointment")` (apologies for any syntax problems, it's been a while since I wrote C#). Once you've done that, show the updated code snippet and its output in your question.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I did exactly what you wanted me to do. It didn't throw any Exception, which means that the the CurrentUser exists.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are not authorized to the Database, check the Rules Tab in the Realtime database.

1. Open firebase, select database on the left hand side.
2. Now on the right hand side, select **Realtime database** from the dropdown and change the rules to allow anyone to write the Database

   ```
   {

    "rules": {
   ".read": true,
   ".write": true
   }
   }
   ```

Your rule is:

```
{
 "rules": {
".read": "auth != null",
".write":"auth != null"
 }
 }
```

This means only authorized user's can write and read the Data.

Comment: That is exactly what I want. I only want to allow the authorized users to access to the Firebase Database and not anybody.

Comment: @Hashmat About LoginWithEmailPassword, you can take a look:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49607811/firebase-email-passord-authentication-using-xamarin-forms-with-net-standard-vs